# Падение приложения при возврате после перехода по внешней ссылке

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windowsphone

Разрабатываю приложение для Windows Phone системы, на странице имеется кнопка типа `HyperlinkButton` , при ее нажатии приложение переходит на определенный  Url запуская стандартный браузер, после этого приложение закрывается, и нельзя вернуться в него нажав кнопку Back.

Так же, при совершении данной операции через проект запущенный в VS 12 кнопка Back возвращает в приложение. Но если сделать те же действия в приложении запущенном не через VS(через это приложение задеплоиное на телефоне) то оно закрывается.

В чем может быть причина? В каком направлении копать?

Провел эксперимент с состояниями(suspending /resuming), только на этой станице где переход по Url осуществляется происходит такое, на других все работает нормально. При переходе в suspending все хорошо, как только делаю resuming - валится ошибка такая.

```
    A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in
    WinRT information: GetNavigationState doesn't support serialization of a parameter type which was passed to Frame.Navigate.
    A first chance exception of type 'Name.Common.SuspensionManagerException' occurred in
    A first chance exception of type 'Name.Common.SuspensionManagerException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
    A first chance exception of type 'Name.Common.SuspensionManagerException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем то немного покопав информации в интернетах нарыл такую вещь, что при переходе из одной страницы на другую( посредством Frame.Navigate) необходимо передавать в качестве параметра простейшие данные(строки, числа), большие объекты программа при сворачивании в стек не записывает, оттого и валится такая ошибка.

Comment: Передавать объекты, которые поддерживают System.Runtime.Serialization. Это могут быть и болеесложные объекты, реализовавшие ISerializable(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable(v=vs.110).aspx)